# Remove double quotes within the column value using Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I am working on Processing a (90 Cols) CSV File - Semicolon Separated (;) {case can be ignore and I am aware file standard is a mess but I am helpless in that regards}

Input Rows :

```
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"ASDASDA"asads";"123";"456"
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"12322AAasd"asads";"123";"456"
"Lmnop";"asdasads";"mer";"123;2343;asa"dwd";"456"
```

Output Expected :

```
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"ASDASDA asads";"123";"456"
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"12322AAasd asads";"123";"456"
"Lmnop";"asdasads";"mer";"123;2343;asa dwd";"456"
```

(Double Quote can be replaced by Space or blank). {Kindly note - even though this is ';' seperated file some rows have ';' within quoted data for a column.

Issue : In the rows - I am getting an extra Double Quote within the quoted data.

Please advise me on how to handle this in Unix.

Comment: It is not possible to write a tool to parse a file formatted like that (which does not conform to any CSV "standard") because you show that a quoted field can itself contain unescaped quotes and/or semi-colons and so there is no way to know where a field starts/ends. For example, if you can have a field like `"123;2343;asa"dwd"` then you can have a field like `"123;2343;asa";"dwd"` (I just added 1 more `"` and 1 more `;` to it) and that is indistinguishable from 2 fields `"123;2343;asa"` and `"dwd"`

Answer (score 2):

one trick you can use is to remove `"` not around the field boundaries. A simple `sed` script can be

```
$ sed -E 's/([^;])"([^;])/\1 \2/g' file
```

note that if you allow escaped quote marks is you fields, this is going to remove them as well.

note the example below in the comments which is not covered with one round of the `sed`. Due to greedy match a single char can't be a condition for both matches, so `"a"b"c";` won't work correctly.

Comment: I would think OP wants `"a"b"c";` converted to `"abc";`

Comment: this should do so, did you test? I would be surprised if not.

Comment: `echo '"a"b"c";' | sed -E 's/([^\b;])"([^\b;])/\1 \2/g'` result
`"a"b"c";`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Greedy capture will consume single character "b" for the first capture and won't work for the next.

Answer (score 0):

What would you think of the following solution:

1. Replace all `";"` by `;`
2. Remove all remaining `"`
3. Replace all `;` back into `";"`
4. Add additional `"` characters, at the beginning and at the end of every line.

The whole thing can be done with `tr` or `sed` or whatever command you prefer.

Comment: How? `sed 's/";"/;/g;s/"//g;s/;/";"/g;s/.*/"&"/' ` will not work when `;"123;2343;asa"dwd";` should be converted to `;"123;2343;asadwd";`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'NF*(gsub(__," ",$!(NF=NF))^_ +gsub(OFS,FS) +gsub("^ | $",__))' \
>                __='\42'  FS='\442\73\42' OFS='\31\17'
> ```

```
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"ASDASDA asads";"123";"456"
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"12322AAasd asads";"123";"456"
"Lmnop";"asdasads";"mer";"123;2343;asa dwd";"456"
```

Answer (score 0):

This transform is easy to do using tool which provide regular expression with zero-length assertions (lookbehind and lookahead), as you applied `unix` tag there is good chance you have `perl` command and therefore I propose following solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"ASDASDA"asads";"123";"456"
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"12322AAasd"asads";"123";"456"
"Lmnop";"asdasads";"mer";"123;2343;asa"dwd";"456"
```

then

```
perl -p -e 's/(?<=[[:alnum:]])"(?=[[:alnum:]])/ /g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"ASDASDA asads";"123";"456"
"AAAAA";"ABABDBDA";"12322AAasd asads";"123";"456"
"Lmnop";"asdasads";"mer";"123;2343;asa dwd";"456"
```

Explanation: I inform `perl` that I want to use it `sed`-style via `-p -e` then I provide substitution (`s`): `"` which is after alphanumeric character (letter or digit) and before alphanumeric should be replaced using space character. This is applied to all such `"` that is globally (`g`).

Note: you might elect to port that answer to any other tools which does provide ability to replace regular expression with zero-length assertions.

*(tested in perl 5, version 26, subversion 3)*

Answer (score 0):

When you consider the combination `";"` as a delimiter, you can use

```
awk -F '";"' '{
  printf "\"";
  for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
    gsub("\"","", $i);
    printf("%s\";\"",$i)
  };
  print $NF 
}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^(("[^"]*";)*"[^"]*)"([^;])/\1 \3/;ta' file
```

Iterate starting from the start of the line, match zero or more correctly double quoted fields followed by an incorrect double quote and replace that double quote by a space.